# File Open Dialog Box With Password

Tags: excel, vba

I am using below codes but there another password **456** also to be tried on fail. Can you please guide how to do that.

````
  With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xls", 1
        .Show

        fullpath = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With


    If InStr(fullpath, ".xls") = 0 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Workbooks.Open fullpath, ReadOnly:=False, Password:="123"
    Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
    Range("A2").Select


End Sub```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test if the first password try was successful, if not try the other password.

```
Dim OpenWb As Workbook

On Error Resume Next 'if Workbooks.Open errors hide these messages
Set OpenWb = Workbooks.Open(fullpath, ReadOnly:=False, Password:="123")

If OpenWb Is Nothing Then 'if first faild try second
    Set OpenWb = Workbooks.Open(fullpath, ReadOnly:=False, Password:="456")
End If
On Error Goto 0 'always re-enable error reporting!

If OpenWb Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "Both passwords were wrong"
    Exit Sub 'cancel here
Else
    With OpenWb.Worksheets(1)
        .Rows("2:" & .Rows.Count).ClearContents
        .Range("A2").Select
    End With
End If
```